# room temperature water or room-temperature

Tags: word-difference

Do we say 'room temperature water'? Is the phrase 'room temperature' an adjective? Do we use this with a hyphen? Which of the following is correct?

---

I like to drink room temperature water.

---

I like to drink room-temperature water.

---

I like to drink water at room temperature.

Answer (score 1):

All three examples are correct.

"Room temperature" as such is not hyphenated. It's made of two nouns, from which room is a [noun adjunct or modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

You [hyphenate room-temperature, when it acts as an adjective](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/room-temperature) as in "room-temperature water." I've often seen [nonhyphenated "room temperature water,"](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&hl=en&authuser=0&ei=1grUXO3YI4PYwQKp7JugAw&q=site%3Agov%20%22room%20temperatuire%20water%22&oq=site%3Agov%20%22room%20temperatuire%20water%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...399317.407504..408097...0.0..0.81.1848.34......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0j0i131j0i67j0i10.ohTQCBb1YIw) though, so I guess that could also be correct.